# Google Earth Engine export multiples images in one task

Tags: python, google-earth-engine

I am facing to a problem caused by the number of requests that can be done with the Google Earth Engine Python API is limited to 3000.

Since I have a lot of small disparate images with different regions to export I reach this limit every time. Then to reduce the number of requests done to the Python API I would like to clip these images in one task. The problem is each image corresponds to a different region and following the documentation it seems that it is not possible to get a list of region linked to images clipped.

A pseudo-code based on the existing code would be:

```
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: [img1, img2, ..., imgn],
  folder: "name",
  description: 'descr',
  scale: 30,
  region: [geometry1, geometry2, ..., geometryn]
});
```

Is it a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "global" image with everything outside your ROIs masked and then skip the export of the empty tiles, effectively exporting all your regions in just a single export. Depending on the size of your ROIs you might want to adapt the size of each tile with the `fileDimensions` parameter.

Assuming you have all your ROIs in a single MultiPolygon feature called `rois`.

```js
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: img.clip(rois),
  folder: "name",
  description: 'descr',
  scale: 30,
  region: rois,
  skipEmptyTiles: True
});
```

Comment: Ho ok and is it possible in that case to assign a specific description to each roi during the save to drive ? Then after the file saved to drive I need to parse it into single files isn't it?